# Resolution of X-ray crystallography

Tags: proteins, lab-techniques, protein-structure, xray-crystallography

A structure determined by X-ray crystallography has a resolution of 1.5 Å. When I look at the coordinates, I find every backbone C-N distance is 1.32 Å.i.e. Accurately predicted. If resolution is not good why every C-N bond distance is accurately predicted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The structural model of a protein is obtained using both experimental data and prior knowledge about geometry of macromolecules. As a structural model is refined, interatomic distances are also restrained. So, the C-N distance isn't really predicted. Alternatively, knowledge about this distance is used to construct reasonable model.

In response to the comment below I'll cite Rupp's *Biomolecular Crystallography*, the most comprehensive book on this subject. Refinement and restraints are covered in Chapter 12, *Model building and refinement*.

> An observation does not have to be an experimental observation
>   (measured data) specific to the particular structure, but can be any
>   type of general prior knowledge regarding molecular stereochemistry.
>   Known stereochemistry can be exploited and implemented in
>   macromolecular refinement in the form of geometric constraints and
>   restraints. [...]
>
> We know from accurate and precise small molecule and peptide fragment
>   structures [...] that bond lengths and bond angles show distinct and
>   relatively narrow distributions around their mean positions. [...]
>
> Refinement programs read restraint target values specific for each
>   residue and each ligand molecule from restraint library files, which
>   are subject to continuous empirical update.

The value given in this book (Table 12-1) for peptide bond C-N is 1.336 Å with variance 0.023 Å.

Comment: it's always helpful to include resources for external validation - it may seem silly when the answer is common knowledge in your field, but it is very helpful to those outside of a specific field.

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh: I've added a citation